# Broken layout on mobile when responding to job inquiries

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On Chrome 68 on Android, I see this at https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages:
[image]

Comment: It's even worse than misnested tags in phpBB... wtf caused this?!

Comment: Sadly, the jobs messages center simply isn't mobile-friendly. I wish I had a better answer for you. :-( Would you explain how you ended up on this page on your phone?

Comment: @Max yeah, what kind of place does that to their HR people?

Comment: Oh my. That is garbage.

Comment: @Max: I clicked a link from an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report! We've given the Messages page a lick of paint and fixed the mobile layout bugs.

I'm very sorry for taking so long to address this. The code for the Messages page is *not great* - one of those situations where fixing one bug causes two more somewhere else. Accordingly it took a long time to make sure everything was stable, even for a relatively superficial change such as this.